# Jquery Datatables ReloadAjax

Tags: jquery, datatables

I'm trying to use the reloadajax function however when I run it the table says processing and nothing happens. The button and everything works inside the table it just doesn't reload the table and gets stuck. Any Ideas why?

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
$.fn.dataTableExt.oApi.fnReloadAjax = function ( oSettings, sNewSource, fnCallback, bStandingRedraw )
{
    // DataTables 1.10 compatibility - if 1.10 then versionCheck exists.
    // 1.10s API has ajax reloading built in, so we use those abilities
    // directly.
    if ( $.fn.dataTable.versionCheck ) {
        var api = new $.fn.dataTable.Api( oSettings );

        if ( sNewSource ) {
            api.ajax.url( sNewSource ).load( fnCallback, !bStandingRedraw );
        }
        else {
            api.ajax.reload( fnCallback, !bStandingRedraw );
        }
        return;
    }

    if ( sNewSource !== undefined && sNewSource !== null ) {
        oSettings.sAjaxSource = sNewSource;
    }

    // Server-side processing should just call fnDraw
    if ( oSettings.oFeatures.bServerSide ) {
        this.fnDraw();
        return;
    }

    this.oApi._fnProcessingDisplay( oSettings, true );
    var that = this;
    var iStart = oSettings._iDisplayStart;
    var aData = [];

    this.oApi._fnServerParams( oSettings, aData );

    oSettings.fnServerData.call( oSettings.oInstance, oSettings.sAjaxSource, aData, function(json) {
        /* Clear the old information from the table */
        that.oApi._fnClearTable( oSettings );

        /* Got the data - add it to the table */
        var aData =  (oSettings.sAjaxDataProp !== "") ?
            that.oApi._fnGetObjectDataFn( oSettings.sAjaxDataProp )( json ) : json;

        for ( var i=0 ; i<aData.length ; i++ )
        {
            that.oApi._fnAddData( oSettings, aData[i] );
        }

        oSettings.aiDisplay = oSettings.aiDisplayMaster.slice();

        that.fnDraw();

        if ( bStandingRedraw === true )
        {
            oSettings._iDisplayStart = iStart;
            that.oApi._fnCalculateEnd( oSettings );
            that.fnDraw( false );
        }

        that.oApi._fnProcessingDisplay( oSettings, false );

        /* Callback user function - for event handlers etc */
        if ( typeof fnCallback == 'function' && fnCallback !== null )
        {
            fnCallback( oSettings );
        }
    }, oSettings );
};



$(document).ready(function() {




     $('#example').dataTable( {
                "bProcessing": true,
                "sAjaxSource": 'test2.php',
                "bJQueryUI": true,
                "bPaginate": true,
                "sScrollX": "",
                "bSortClasses": false,
                "aaSorting": [[0,'asc']],
                "bAutoWidth": true,
                "bInfo": true,
                "sScrollY": "100%",
                "sScrollX": "100%",
                "bScrollCollapse": true,
                "sPaginationType": "full_numbers"

    });

    //Non registered checkouts
$(document).on('click', '.checkinNoReg', function() {

   var id_of_item_to_approve = $(this).attr("id");

   $.ajax({
      url: "test3.php",
      type: "POST",
      data: "eventid=<?PHP echo $eventId;?>" + "&id=" + id_of_item_to_approve, 
      success: function(){
          $('#example').dataTable().fnReloadAjax();

      },
      error:function(){
          alert("Fail");
      }   
    });

});


} );

</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Is the ajax call sending the request and receiving the response correctly?

Check your console to make sure that you are receiving a response and that no errors are thrown during the process, or try executing the ajax call in isolation.

This has always been the problem when I have experienced this, the processing message remains as it is waiting for a response that it never gets, rather than it being a problem with the way that you have set up the datatable.

You must ensure that no unexpected ajax errors have occurred, further info [here](http://datatables.net/forums/discussion/7325/processing-notice-and-ajax-error-handling/p1).